# Why KVM VPS is slower then OPENVZ

Tags: kvm-virtualization, openvz

so i just purchased one KVM vps and when i bench it and compare it with my existing openvz vps i found it that its slower that openvz vps and when i checked processor info its bit wrong info so am wondering can the company control to share the cpu cache between different KVM containers or not ?

on kvm : cat /proc/cpuinfo

```
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 79
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz
stepping        : 1
microcode       : 0x1
cpu MHz         : 2199.996
cache size      : 4096 KB
bogomips        : 4399.99
```

i checked on intel site  this E5 processor have about 30 MB cache.

on openvz vps : cat /proc/cpuinfo

```
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 63
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1660 v3 @ 3.00GHz
stepping        : 2
microcode       : 46
cpu MHz         : 2999.918
cache size      : 20480 KB
bogomips        : 5999.83
```

cache size is 20 MB which is real.

after that i did cpu bench

on kvm : sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=20000 run

```
Maximum prime number checked in CPU test: 20000


Test execution summary:
    total time:                          30.1875s
    total number of events:              10000
    total time taken by event execution: 30.1860
    per-request statistics:
         min:                                  2.57ms
         avg:                                  3.02ms
         max:                                  4.13ms
         approx.  95 percentile:               3.22ms

Threads fairness:
    events (avg/stddev):           10000.0000/0.00
    execution time (avg/stddev):   30.1860/0.00
```

on openvz : sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=20000 run

```
Maximum prime number checked in CPU test: 20000


Test execution summary:
    total time:                          26.5902s
    total number of events:              10000
    total time taken by event execution: 26.5889
    per-request statistics:
         min:                                  2.64ms
         avg:                                  2.66ms
         max:                                  3.17ms
         approx.  95 percentile:               2.70ms

Threads fairness:
    events (avg/stddev):           10000.0000/0.00
    execution time (avg/stddev):   26.5889/0.00
```

so as you can see there is 4 sec difference which is big thing .

Comment: you dont bench the same metal, sofar its not a try, openvz could be more limited as a kvm, so be happy with the kvm :)

Comment: Please post the command line you used to start KVM. It's very easy to start kvm in emulation mode rather than (para)virtualization mode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:** Your OpenVZ CPU is faster for single-threaded workload than the one used by KVM. On top of that, OpenVZ is a lighter virtualization approach so, all other things being equal, it is somewhat faster than KVM.

**LONG ANSWER:** KVM CPU is a Broadwell Xeon with base/turbo clocks of 2.2-2.9 GHz. OpenVZ uses an Haswell Xeon with base/turbo clocks of 3.0-3.5 GHz. Considering that Haswell and Broadwell IPC is basically the same, it is not a surprise the fastest CPU wins a single-threaded benchmark.

*Regarding the virtualization platforms:*

KVM is a full hardware virtualization platform (full HVM), while OpenVZ uses containerization, with others useing para-virtualization.

The first approach, which basically emulates an entire virtual machine/platform, has the advantage of very high compatibility (even with OS not originally written with virtualization in mind - ie: Windows). The cost is added overhead, which can be quite significant in some workload. Specific para-virtualized drivers can be added to a full HVM setup, avoiding some of the overhead.

Paravirtualization, on the other hand, requires guest OS collaboration (for example, in the form of [hypercalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hypercall&redirect=no)). In other words, the guest OS had to be adapted to run under the specific supervisor/para-virtualizer, and so a para-virtualized host can not run arbitrary guest OS. The advantage is much lower overhead and, so, faster performance.

Containerization is even lower-overhead that paravirtualization, as there is a single OS instance only; every other VPS is a jail/chroot-on-steroid which duplicate the userspace parts, using the very same kernel of the "main" OS. This is at the same time its main strenght and weakness: as it only duplicate user-space tools, overhead is very low. On the other hand, a single kernel is in use for *all* VPS images.

Anyway, the difference between full HVM, paravirtualization and containerization are mainly visible in latency and I/O bound workloads. As your benchmark is a pure CPU stress test, the difference can be mainly attributed to the different CPU configuration (rather than to the different hypervisors).

Comment: Interesting. It has been over 12 years since I last looked at OpenVZ. At that time, it used to be containerization not paravirtualization, when did that change?

Comment: @JörgWMittag you are right: OpenVZ uses containerization rather than paravirtualization. I updated my answer; thanks.